# running Domain, Site and the links

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

The html based menu comes with the `{% show_menu ... %}` tag and this is the only case where links working reliable (especially menu links in this case).
When I try to manually put links onto a page in cms editor and I'd like them to be internal (pointing to other cms based pages), I am regularly stumbling over the automatically prefixed domain, which is coming from the SITE_ID in my prject settings and does not match with the running domain (the domain specified when doing runserver) which in most cases is `localhost`. The domain behind the SITE_ID = 1 is pointing to the future staging domain, which does not exist yet and anyway is out of scope during local development.

What is the secret behind the `{% show_menu ... %}` mechanism compared to the manual created links during design time? I was trying to put links with the bootstrap4 plugin and the feature coming with the editor out of the box. None of them respect the running domain. But `{% show_menu ... %}` always work, regardless of the running domain and SITE_ID configuration.

Btw. I wanted to try out putting a link from the `djangocms-link` plugin, but this anyhow doesn't show up under the plugins list, neither in structure mode nor in page editor mode.

So how can I reach the behavior of `{% show_menu ... %}` links for my manual links at design time - relying onto the running domain, not the site domain?

Comment: How exactly do you "manually put links onto a page"? And is the link plugin in your installed apps? Do you define a `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` and then not include the link plugin in any of your placeholders?

Comment: @markwalker_: 1. I am putting text onto a text plugin of a cms page, then select that text, then chose either the link button of the editor's tool bar or from the CMS Plugins drop down of the editor's toolbar I select Link/Button which is a sub-feature of the Bootstrap 4 plugin. 2. djangocms_link is in installed apps, but it doesn't show up as a plugin as I mentioned in my question. 3. I am not aware of a  `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` and don't specify such explicitly. In my settings it is `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}` and the doc says the plugin shall appear anywhere in that case.

Comment: `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` allows you to limit the plugins available to each placeholder, set defaults etc. If you've just got that as an empty `dict` I'd suggest removing that setting & seeing it that helps because you're not really using the setting.

Comment: @markwalker_: tried to remove, no change. Still no djangocms_link visible neither on structure mode nor on page editor toolbar dropdown. Would expect it under **Generic** or under a separate category like **Link** or so. Btw. the empty setting was generated automatically on project setup time

Comment: I did some tweaks and found that bootstrap4-links do not allow headless urls, meaning urls without protocol and domain name like `/en/mypage`. Version used: `djangocms-bootstrap4==1.3.1`. My current workaround is to modify all occurrences in the db directly (removing the protocol and domain names from the urls): The appropriate table name is `bootstrap4_link_bootstrap4link`. That's pretty annoying, those links are no more editable via the cms text editor frontend plugin!

Comment: Another workaround I just tried is to edit the html source in text editor plugin. This even fails, since bootstrap4 links are somewhat organized by ids and the plugin refuses to store the change to the `href` urls of the link anchor - also annoying. `django-cms==3.6.0`